# Javolution: Removing while iterating through a FastSet

Tags: java, data-structures, javolution

In the docs it says to iterator a FastSet you can do:

```
 for (FastSet.Record r = set.head(), end = set.tail(); (r = r.getNext()) != end;) {
     Object value = set.valueOf(r);    
 }
```

Question is: How to remove while iterating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`delete(r)`](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/util/FastSet.html#delete%28javolution.util.FastCollection.Record%29) method seems apropos, although you may also want to look at the inherited [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) operations, too.

Comment: Ok, but one must be careful to advance the pointer before removing.